# Jsf dynamically created actionListener parameter

Tags: jsf, icefaces, actionlistener

I have a custom facelet component (custom tag) but there is one thing that currently annoys me a lot. I'm trying to pass an action listener as a parameter to the custom tag, in order to make it more dynamic and just doesn't work.

Environment: JSF 1.2, IceFaces 1.8

Here's the way I'm trying to achieve this:

- the command link uses the passed parameter 'paginationController'

  ```
  <h:commandLink id="#{id}-link-three" value="click"
      actionListener="#{paginationController.paginationLinkClicked}" />
  ```
- the parameter 'paginationController' is passed like this:

  ```
  paginationController="rowSelectController"
  ```
- when I click the link, there's what I receive:

  ```
  Received 'javax.el.MethodNotFoundException' when invoking action listener
  '#{paginationController.paginationLinkClicked}' for component 'entity-list-apps-link-three'
  2011-02-22 12:49:47,803 SEVERE [javax.faces.event] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-4)
  javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/jsf/common/components/facelets
  /applicationList.xhtml @107,71 actionListener="#{paginationController.paginationLinkClicked}":
  Method not found: rowSelectController.paginationLinkClicked(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent)
  ```

So it seems that it successfully resolves the bean name to rowSelectController, but it complaints it can't find the method, and the method IS there!

One more thing, if I replace the parameter with the correct controller's name, it just works! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Because `paginationController` is variable you need to use the [] syntax here. Assuming `paginationLinkClicked` is a fixed method name:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{paginationController['paginationLinkClicked']}" />
```

If `paginationLinkClicked` would also be variable, you need to omit the single quotes:

```
<h:commandLink actionListener="#{paginationController[paginationLinkClicked]}" />
```

Comment: Hello Arjan, and thanks a lot for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work, it displays the same message: javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/jsf/common/components/facelets/applicationList.xhtml @109,74 actionListener="#{paginationController['paginationLinkClicked']}": Method not found: rowSelectController.paginationLinkClicked(javax.faces.event.ActionEvent).
The method signature is also correct, no doubt about it: public void paginationLinkClicked(ActionEvent event) {}